# OpenSSL ECDSA Signature Issue

Tags: openssl

I tried the following command to sign a binary file using two different ways to sign. The results are different. I am not sure why or Does it matter? Installed openssl tool under windows environment.

Here is the script:

#create private key:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out private.pem
```

#Method 1:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary test.bin > test_hash.bin

openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey private.pem -in test_hash.bin -out test1.sig
```

#Method 2:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.pem -out test2.sig test.bin
```

test1.sig is different from test2.sig.

Comment: `dgst` hs multiple output expressions. in method1, you use `-binary`, and then sign that digest, but from https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-dgst.html it looks like the default output expression format for dgst is `-hex` so you are probably comparing the signature of a binary file vs the signature of a file containing character data expressing hex.